# C# and .NET specific: Did I get this edit correct?

Tags: support, tags, specific-question

I don't know what I was thinking when I edited this question:

[Is it safe for structs to implement interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces)

back then, but now I feel I may have very well got it wrong. Is this question **C#** specific, or **.NET** specific?

Answer (score 1):

Given the wording of the question, I certainly think it made some sense to do that edit. Though I'm not sure there is any functional difference to the answer between any .NET language.

Your edit would have possibly exposed the question to more people who could have provided good answers, who could be following [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) but not [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over-thinking it. If you are still unsure about it, then perhaps you can add back the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag, and still keep the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)  one. That way the question gets coverage under both tags.